# Evaluate the infinite product $\prod_{k \geq 2}\sqrt[k]{1+\frac{1}{k}}=\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{2}} \sqrt[3]{1+\frac{1}{3}} \sqrt[4]{1+\frac{1}{4}} \cdots$

Tags: sequences-and-series, infinite-product

I can show the convergence of the following infinite product and some bounds for it:

$$\prod_{k \geq 2}\sqrt[k]{1+\frac{1}{k}}=\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{2}} \sqrt[3]{1+\frac{1}{3}} \sqrt[4]{1+\frac{1}{4}} \cdots<$$

$$<\left(1+\frac{1}{4} \right)\left(1+\frac{1}{9} \right)\left(1+\frac{1}{16} \right)\cdots=\prod_{k \geq 2} \left(1+\frac{1}{k^2} \right)=\frac{\sinh \pi}{2 \pi}=1.83804$$

Here I used Euler's product for $\frac{\sin x}{x}$.

The next upper bound is not as easy to evaluate, but still possible, taking two more terms in Taylor's series for $\sqrt[k]{1+\frac{1}{k} }$:

$$\prod_{k \geq 2}\sqrt[k]{1+\frac{1}{k}}<\prod_{k \geq 2} \left(1+\frac{1}{k^2}-\frac{k-1}{2k^4}+\frac{2k^2-3k+1}{6k^6} \right)=$$

$$=\prod_{k \geq 2} \left(1+\frac{1}{k^2}-\frac{1}{2k^3}+\frac{5}{6k^4}-\frac{1}{2k^5}+\frac{1}{6k^6} \right)<$$

$$<\exp \left( \frac{\pi^2}{6}+\frac{\pi^4}{108}+\frac{\pi^6}{5670}-1-\frac{\zeta (3)}{2}-\frac{\zeta (5)}{2} \right)=1.81654$$

The numerical value of the infinite product is approximately:

$$\prod_{k \geq 2}\sqrt[k]{1+\frac{1}{k}}=1.758743628$$

The ISC found no closed from for this number.

> Is there some way to evaluate this product or find better bounds in closed form?

---

**Edit**

Clement C suggested taking logarithm and it was a very useful suggestion, since I get the series:

$$\ln \prod_{k \geq 2}\sqrt[k]{1+\frac{1}{k}}= \frac{1}{2} \ln \left(1+\frac{1}{2} \right)+\frac{1}{3} \ln \left(1+\frac{1}{3} \right)+\dots$$

I don't know how to find the closed form, but I can certainly use it to find the boundaries (since the series for logarithm are very simple).

$$\frac{1}{2} \ln \left(1+\frac{1}{2} \right)+\frac{1}{3} \ln \left(1+\frac{1}{3} \right)+\dots>\sum^{\infty}_{k=2} \frac{1}{k^2}-\frac{1}{2}\sum^{\infty}_{k=2} \frac{1}{k^3}$$

$$\prod_{k \geq 2}\sqrt[k]{1+\frac{1}{k}}>\exp \left( \frac{\pi^2}{6}-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\zeta (3)}{2} \right)=1.72272$$

$$\prod_{k \geq 2}\sqrt[k]{1+\frac{1}{k}}<\exp \left( \frac{\pi^2}{6}+\frac{\pi^4}{270}-\frac{5}{6}-\frac{\zeta (3)}{2} \right)=1.77065$$

$$\prod_{k \geq 2}\sqrt[k]{1+\frac{1}{k}}>\exp \left( \frac{\pi^2}{6}+\frac{\pi^4}{270}-\frac{7}{12}-\frac{\zeta (3)}{2} -\frac{\zeta (5)}{4}\right)=1.75438$$

$$\prod_{k \geq 2}\sqrt[k]{1+\frac{1}{k}}<\exp \left( \frac{\pi^2}{6}+\frac{\pi^4}{270}+\frac{\pi^6}{4725}-\frac{47}{60}-\frac{\zeta (3)}{2} -\frac{\zeta (5)}{4}\right)=1.76048$$

> $$\prod_{k \geq 2}\sqrt[k]{1+\frac{1}{k}}>\exp \left( \frac{\pi^2}{6}+\frac{\pi^4}{270}+\frac{\pi^6}{4725}-\frac{37}{60}-\frac{\zeta (3)}{2} -\frac{\zeta (5)}{4} -\frac{\zeta (7)}{6}\right)=1.75803$$

This method generates much better bounds than my first idea. The last two are very good approximations.

---

**Edit 2**

Actually, would it be correct to write (it gives the correct value of the product):

> $$\prod_{k \geq 2}\sqrt[k]{1+\frac{1}{k}}=\frac{1}{2} \exp \left( \sum_{k \geq 2} \frac{(-1)^k \zeta(k)}{k-1} \right)$$

Comment: My money is on $e^{2\pi/5}/2$. Taking the logarithm and considering instead a sum may help... and starting the product at $1$ instead of $2$ may also -- this is the factor $2$ in my guess.)

Comment: @ClementC., but it's different from the numerical value

Comment: Euler Mac Laurin gives 1.73287 keeping only the first two terms

Comment: The product evaluates to $\simeq 1.0011\cdot \frac{e^{2\pi/5}}{2}$ so the conjecture above seems to be ruled out (this was double checked by also evaluating the series representation).

Comment: I googled the sum (from 1) and found something. https://books.google.com/books?id=Pl5I2ZSI6uAC&pg=PA122&lpg=PA122&dq=1.2577468869&source=bl http://i.imgur.com/w5WQE2E.png

Comment: @tired, I got less accurate value, maybe you could show your calculation in an answer?

Comment: @YuriyS Coming after the battle... too bad, a nice closed form like that one would have appealed to the sense of "magic constants."

Comment: Related questions: [one](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/993665/269624) and [two](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/947484/269624)

Comment: A very related function is $f(x) = \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{(-x)^k \zeta (k)}{k} = x \gamma + \ln (x!)$ with the special case of $f(1) = \gamma$, but I don't know how to transform that for a denominator of $k-1$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know if a closed form exists, but to get geometric convergence, we can use the following.

Since the product starts at $k=2$, we compute the sum
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac1k\log\left(1+\frac1k\right)
&=\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac1k\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{nk^n}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}n\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac1{k^{n+1}}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n-1}\frac{\zeta(n+1)-1}{n}\\[6pt]
&=0.564599706384424320592667709038
\end{align}
$$
Note that $\frac{\zeta(n+1)-1}{n}\sim\frac1{n2^{n+1}}$. This gives better than geometric convergence.

Applying $e^x$, we get
$$
\prod_{k=2}^\infty\left(1+\frac1k\right)^{1/k}=1.75874362795118482469989684966
$$

Answer (score 8):

**This is not an answer**, but it's important and I post it separately from the question itself.

I found in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1065075/269624) by @RandomVariable the following series:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\ln (k+1)}{k(k+1)}=\frac{\pi^2}{4}-1-4\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\arctan x}{1+x^{2}} \frac{dx}{e^{\pi x}+1}=\frac{\pi^2}{4}-1-4\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{t~dt}{e^{\pi \tan t}+1} $$

They are related to $\gamma_1$ - Stieltjes constant.

This same series also appeared in [this paper](http://www.people.fas.harvard.edu/~sfinch/csolve/kz3.pdf)  by Steven Finch, page 5.

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\ln (k+1)}{k(k+1)}=1.2577468869$$

This is the same numerical value as:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\ln (1+\frac{1}{k})}{k}=1.2577468869$$

Which is confirmed in [this paper](http://www.people.fas.harvard.edu/~sfinch/csolve/kz.pdf) by the same author, page 3, where this form of the series is used.

It is connected to the integral (page 2, the same paper):

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\ln (1+\frac{1}{k})}{k}=-\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{\ln (y-[y])}{y^2}dy$$

Where $[y]$ is the floor function, meaning $y-[y]$ is the fractional part of $y$.

In [another paper](https://math.dartmouth.edu/~carlp/factorial.pdf) this series is connected to the numer of divisors of $n!$, however slightly different integral representation is used (page 3):

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\ln (1+\frac{1}{k})}{k}=\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{\ln ([y]+1)}{y^2}dy$$

And finally, this is slightly related to [Alladi-Grinstead Constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Alladi-GrinsteadConstant.html), which is given by:

$$e^{c-1}$$

$$c=\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{\ln (\frac{k}{k-1})}{k}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\ln (1+\frac{1}{k})}{k+1}=0.788530566$$

See also the original Alladi and Grinstead paper [here](http://www.academia.edu/17531988/On_the_decomposition_of_n_into_prime_powers).

And this is also somehow connected to the Luroth series representations of real numbers.

Oh, and thanks to @SteveKass for [this useful link](https://books.google.com/books?id=Pl5I2ZSI6uAC&pg=PA122&lpg=PA122&dq=1.2577468869&source=bl).

---

Comparing the convergence of three series, we find that even though they are equivalent, the convergence rate is drastically different.

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\ln (k+1)}{k(k+1)}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\ln (1+\frac{1}{k})}{k}=\sum_{k = 2}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k \zeta(k)}{k-1}$$

[image: Convergence]

---

We can also obtain the following interesting equality:

$$(1+1)\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{2}} \sqrt[3]{1+\frac{1}{3}} \sqrt[4]{1+\frac{1}{4}} \cdots=\sqrt{2} \sqrt[6]{3} \sqrt[12]{4} \sqrt[20]{5} \sqrt[30]{6} \cdots=\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}(k+1)^{\frac{1}{k(k+1)}}$$

Comment: Re: "This same series also appeared [...] This is the same numerical value as:": showing equality of the two (series, not deriving their value) is not too hard -- I assume you don't need it, but in case you do it's a matter of 3-4 lines.

Comment: Which one? The 0.788530566 one?

Comment: I have nothing really conclusive in making a useful connection between the values... what sort of relation are you hoping for?

Comment: I don't know. It came up in my search and S. Finch hinted at some kind of connection.

Comment: $$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{1}{k}\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)
&=\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{\ln(k+1)-\ln(k)}{k}\\
&=\lim_{N\to\infty}\left(\sum_{k=2}^{N}\frac{\ln(k+1)}{k}-\sum_{k=2}^{N}\frac{\ln(k)}{k}\right)\\
&=\lim_{N\to\infty}\left(\sum_{k=2}^{N}\frac{\ln(k+1)}{k}-\sum_{k=1}^{N-1}\frac{\ln(k+1)}{k+1}\right)\\
&=\lim_{N\to\infty}\left(\frac{\ln(N+1)}{N}+\sum_{k=2}^{N-1}\frac{\ln(k+1)}{k(k+1)}-\frac{\ln(2)}{2}\right)\\
&=\lim_{N\to\infty}\left(\sum_{k=2}^{N-1}\frac{\ln(k+1)}{k(k+1)}\right)-\frac{\ln(2)}{2}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\ln(k+1)}{k(k+1)}\\
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 2):

As already discussed above by Yuriy S and others, the product is intimately linked with the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} { \ln(n+1) \over n(n+1) } \approx 1.2577\dots$. The connection is derived as follows:

$$ \prod_{k=2}^{\infty} \left( 1+ {1\over k} \right)^{1/k} \\
=\exp \left( \ln \left(  \prod_{k=2}^{\infty} \left( 1+ {1\over k} \right)^{1/k}  \right) \right) \\
= \exp \left(  \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \ln \left( \left( 1+ {1\over k} \right)^{1/k} \right) \right) \\
= \exp \left(  \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} { \ln\left({k+1 \over k}\right)\over k }  \right) \\
=\exp \left( \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} {\ln(k+1)\over k } -\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} {\ln(k) \over k} \right)\\
=\exp \left( \sum_{n=3}^{\infty} {\ln(k) \over k-1} -\sum_{n=3}^{\infty} {\ln(k) \over k} - {1 \over 2}\ln 2  \right)\\
=\exp \left(    \sum_{n=3}^{\infty} {\ln(k) \over k(k-1)} - {1 \over 2}\ln 2    \right)\\
=\exp \left(  \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} {\ln(k+1) \over k(k+1)} - {1 \over 2}\ln 2   \right)\\
=\exp \left(  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {\ln(k+1) \over k(k+1)} - {1 \over 2}\ln 2 - {1 \over 2}\ln 2   \right)\\
=e^{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {\ln(k+1) \over k(k+1)}} \cdot e^{-\ln 2}\\
={1 \over 2}e^{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {\ln(k+1) \over k(k+1)}} $$

Therefore the product will only have a closed form if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {\ln(k+1) \over k(k+1)}$ has a closed form.

Comment: This seems to imply a relation to the derivative of the reimann zeta function: $\zeta ' (s) = -\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\ln (n)}{n^s}$

Answer (score 2):

Working off of other people's findings, you can write
$$\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{(-x)^k \zeta (k)}{k} = x \gamma + \ln (\Gamma(x+1))$$
$$\frac{d}{dx}\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{(-x)^k \zeta (k)}{k} = -\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} (-x)^{k-1} \zeta (k)=\gamma+\psi(x+1)=H_x$$
$$\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} (-x)^{k-2} \zeta (k)=\frac{H_x}{x}$$
$$\int_0^{x} \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} (-y)^{k-2}\zeta (k) dy = -\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{(-x)^{k-1}\zeta (k)}{k-1} = -\int_0^x \frac{H_y}{y} dy$$
$$\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{(-x)^{k}\zeta (k)}{k-1} = x\int_0^x \frac{H_y}{y} dy$$
However, I believe $\int_0^1 \frac{H_x}{x} dx$ has no closed form, meaning that $$\prod_{k=2}^{\infty} \sqrt[k]{1+\frac{1}{k}}=\frac{1}{2} \exp \left(\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k \zeta(k)}{k-1}\right)=\frac{1}{2}\exp \left({\int_0^1 \frac{H_x}{x} dx} \right)$$ has no closed form either.